# Download a zip file using ajax response

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, http, ashx

I need to download a zip file using ajax and ashx. Currently I am using the code https://stackoverflow.com/a/23797348 but the downloaded zip file is invalid.

The ashx code i am using is :

```
MemoryStream exportPrjtResponseMemStream = SomeClass.ReturnResponse(ID);

Response.ContentType = "application/zip";

Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + fileName + ".zip\"");

Response.CacheControl = "Private";

Response.AppendHeader("Content-Length", exportPrjtResponseMemStream.Length.ToString());                            
exportPrjtResponseMemStream.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream);

Response.Flush();

Response.End();
```

Please suggest.

Comment: please format you code using ctrl+k. it's unreadable

Comment: @MichalHainc there is no delta between the two files both are of same size.

Comment: @MichalHainc: I have recieved the stream correctly in browser but somehow it gets corrupted while downloading. When I am passing the url as SRC in IFrame it is downloading correctly but the file corrupts if I am using ajax request.

Answer (score 0):

- Are you setting '[Response.BufferOutput=true](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.outputstream%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)'  ?
- Once you read the MemoryStream (exportPrjtResponseMemStream) set the position to 0  `exportPrjtResponseMemStream.Position=0` before using it to write to OutputStream.
- Try using '[Response.OutputStream.Flush()](http://forums.asp.net/t/1482010.aspx?Difference%20among%20Response%20Output%20Flush%20Response%20OutputStream%20Flush%20and%20Response%20End%20)'

My guess is the ResponseStream is not being properly built. Also try setting all the headers as per the solution in [your link above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16086162/handle-file-download-from-ajax-post).

HTH!

Comment: Yes i am setting the headers correctly also i am getting the memory stream in browser response but it is not downloading.

Comment: Hi, Can you remove `Response.End()` and try?  Why I asked "Response.BufferOutput=true" is because you don't need to call `Response.End()` after `Response.Flush()`.  Otherwise, use  `Response.Clear(); exportPrjtResponseMemStream.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream); Response.End(); `

Comment: Also, please be careful about the case sensitivity of the headers. I mean `Response.CacheControl="private"`.  I see you mention your code is working with iframe, otherwise I would suggest manual writing of MemoryStream as in [this link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/812406)